# Prolog: get symbol predicate

Tags: prolog

I have a symbol table with structure:

```
key → [value | R]
```

I would like to write a predicate get_symbol/2, which receives a key (its first parameter) and combines a value (its second parameter) to the first value associated with key in the symbol table.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: Combine how? And aren't you missing a predicate argument (to return the combination)?

Comment: Dear @PauloMoura, I think the second parameter will be the combination argument. Thanks!

Comment: If the second parameter contains the value, then it can't also contain the combination. You would need a 3rd parameter. Also, what is `R`?

Comment: Yes, I know `R` is the *rest of the list*, but didn't know what significance it has in your symbol table. So you're saying each key has one or more values associated with it? Can you give an example of a `get_symbol/2` query they way you expect it to work? And how is your symbol table structured?

Comment: Dear @lurker, yah the English in requirement rather ambiguous, I wonder if this implement would be the case: get_symbol(K, [(K,A)|_]) :- A \== [].
get_symbol(K, [(Y,_)|R]) :- K \== Y, get_symbol(K,R)

Comment: As @PauloMoura mentioned, you're missing an argument for actually passing back the value. So, for example: `get_symbol(K, [(K, A)|_], A).` and `get_symbol(K, [(Y,_)|R], A) :- dif(K, Y), get_symbol(K, R, A).` will yield the value of key `K` in the 3rd argument.

Comment: Dear @lurker, can I write another predicate to get back the result as this predicate should only have 2 arguments. Thanks!

Comment: As i asked before, please show at least one example of how you expect to call your predicate. It will help clarify a lot of things.

Comment: `key → [value|Rest]` is a logical description, but does not explain how `get_symbol/2` in Prolog is supposed to know about the symbol table or how to access it. One argument to `get_symbol/2` is the key. That means that the second argument, if you are only allowed two arguments, must be the value. That further means you are left with no more arguments you can use to pass the symbol table. So how is symbol table access supposed to work for your problem? Is it asserted as Prolog facts? If so, is each key/value pair asserted as an individual fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual representation of the symbol table has not been described. Let's assume a logical representation which would be a set of facts, `sym_table(Key, Value).` The symbol table would then be facts:

```
sym_table(key1, [val1_1, val1_2, ...]).
sym_table(key2, [val2_1, val2_2, ...]).
...
```

Then your `get_symbol/2` predicate, which obtains the first value for a given key, would look like:

```
get_symbol(Key, Value) :-
    sym_table(Key, [Value | _]).
```

Note that this predicate will fail, as expected (and I presume desired), if (1) the `Key` does not exist in the symbol table, or (2) the `Key` has no values (it is represented as `sym_table(Key, []).` in the database).

Comment: @LeKimTrang I'm glad I was able to help. If I answered your question, perhaps you could be so kind as to mark my answer accepted (click the checkmark) and/or upvote the answer as "useful". Thanks.